# Combining different columns with overlapping index in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a pandas Dataframe which looks like this:

```
  ABC_1 ABC_2 ABC_3 ABC_4
    x    y       z    k
    NaN  y       NaN  k
    x    NaN      z   NaN
    x    NaN      z   k
    ...  ...     ...  ...
```

This is just one column `ABC` which has been split into many columns. Similarly there are other columns like `PQR` which has been split into different parts.

- Each column contains 100 values(including NaNs), i.e. the shape of the `df` can be considered as `(100,4)` in this case.
- I want to combine all the four columns into a single column named `ABC` but it should contain all the values from all the four columns. `NaN` values can be removed beforehand or after concatenating so that's not a concern, although I feel that removing all `NaNs` at once after concatenating will be more efficient.

In short the new column should look like this:

```
   ABC
   x
   x
   x
   y
   y
   z
   z
   z
   k
   k
   k
   ...
```

What I tried:

I tried to use `pd.concat` but it didn't work as it throws `duplicate index error` which is obvious from the case. Now, there are ways to deal with this but I don't think it will computationally efficient if the dataframe is quite big.

I tried putting all values into a single list and then assigning it to the column of a new dataframe but as I said, the dataframe can be huge and list would occupy a lot of space.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this efficiently?

Edit: There can be one more situation. It is not necessary for all the column names to follow the same pattern. For example the above dataframe also contain columns like this

```
ABC_1 ABC_2 ABC_3 ABC_4 ABC_5_patt
    x    y       z    k    p
    NaN  y       NaN  k    p
    x    NaN      z   NaN  p
    x    NaN      z   k    NaN
    ...  ...     ...  ...  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and for remove MultiIndex [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), last [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) for convert Series to one column `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.unstack().dropna().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('ABC')
print (df)
   ABC
0    x
1    x
2    x
3    y
4    y
5    z
6    z
7    z
8    k
9    k
10   k
```

If possible multiple categories:

```
print (df)
  ABC_1 PQR_2 ABC_3 PQR_4
0     x     y     z     k
1   NaN     y   NaN     k
2     x   NaN     z   NaN
3     x   NaN     z     k

df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.unstack().dropna().reset_index(level=[1,2],drop=True)
df.index = [df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), df.index]
df = df.unstack()
print (df)
  ABC  PQR
0   x    y
1   x    y
2   x    k
3   z    k
4   z    k
5   z  NaN
```

Comment: what if the other columns contains pattern like this `PQR_4_text`?

Comment: @mlRocks - Can you explain more? It depends of data mainly.

Comment: Sure. For example, it is not necessary that all columns contain only two values after splitting on `_`. It might be the case that one of the columns in the above example which you have given could have been `PQR_4_text` instead of just `PQR_4`

Comment: @mlRocks - Can you add data sample and expected output?

Comment: @mlRocks - I see your edit, so need `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True, n=1)` for second solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
x = {"ABC_1": [1, np.nan, 2], "ABC_2": [3, 4, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

This is what the `df` looks like:

```
   ABC_1  ABC_2
0    1.0    3.0
1    NaN    4.0
2    2.0    NaN
```

You can create a series like this:

```
s = pd.concat([df[col] for col in df.columns])
s = s[s.notnull()]
```

This is what `s` looks like:

```
0    1.0
2    2.0
0    3.0
1    4.0
```

You can re-index `s` if required